# Numbers written as $a^b+b$ for $a,b\geq 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a sequence of $102$ consecutive positive integers, among which exactly $100$ satisfy the property that they can be written as $a^b+b$ for some integers $a,b\geq 2$?

This looks somewhat similar to finding a sequence of consecutive integers that are all composite numbers. For that we can use the sequence $n!+2,n!+3,\ldots,n!+n$ for any $n$, but for writing numbers as $a^b+b$ what can we use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call a number nice if it is of the form $a^b+b$.

Let $A_k=\{k+1,k+2\dots ,k+102\}$ and let $f(k)$ be the number of nice numbers in $A_k$.

If $d$ divides $n$ then $2^n+d$ is nice since $2^n+d=(2^{n/d})^d+d$.

From here $A_{2^{102!}}=\{2^{102!}+1,2^{102!}+2,\dots ,2^{102!}+102\}$ has $102$ nice numbers.

Notice $f(0)\leq 100$ since $1$ and $2$ are not nice.

Since $f(k)$ differs from $f(k+1)$ by at most $1$ for all $k$ and $f(0)\leq 100 \leq f(2^{102!})$ we conclude there is an $i$ between $0$ and $2^{102!}$ with $f(i)=100$.

So $A_i$ is the set of consecutive integers you want.

Comment: "...among which exactly 100 satisfy the property..."

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you very much, my bad. Fixed.

Comment: I think you have missed $!$ in exponents in few places.

Comment: Oh yeah${}{}{}{}{}$.